# Demonstration and Interpretation between a Fisher matrix and its dual space which is covariance matrix

Tags: conditional-probability, covariance, covariance-matrix, fisher-information, duality

I have a simple (maybe not) issue about the interpretation of the link between Fisher information matrix and its inverse which is the covariance matrix.

How to formulate that a line of Covariance matrix by Element-Wise Multiplication with the correponding column of Fisher matrix will give the value 1 (product of both matrices gives identity matrix).

In other words, how to prove that, starting from the Fisher information definition :

$$I(\theta)=-\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Y}}\left[\frac{d^{2}}{d \theta^{2}} \log p(Y \mid \theta)\right]$$

we have : $$\sum_{j=1}^{n} I_{ij}(\theta)\,\text{Cov}(\theta_{j},\theta_{i})=1$$

It looks like the result of a probability equal to 1 for example with a $\text{PDF}=f(\theta)$ :

$$P(-\infty < \theta < +\infty) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(\theta) \text{d}\theta = 1$$

But I don't know how to better explicit this product wised-element between a row and a column which gives a value of 1.

If someone had a rigorous demonstration about the quantities involved (even if I know there are variance, covariance and Hessian terms of factors but I make confusions to demonstrate that we get a value equal to 1 for all diagonal elements, i.e getting an identity matrix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result that you seem to be referring to relates the inverse of the Fisher information matrix to the *asymptotic* covariance matrix of the *maximum likelihood estimator* (MLE). Note that this is an *asymptotic* result, i.e. it applies only in the limit of infinite sample size, it is *not* a general property. More specifically, under some regularity conditions (which don't always hold), the distribution of the MLE converges in the limit of infinite sample size to a multivariate normal distribution with covariance matrix $I(\theta)^{-1}$.

This implies that the MLE is asymptotically *efficient*, i.e. it reaches the lowest possible variance for any unbiased estimator (see [Cramer Rao bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound) and [Maximum likelihood Efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Efficiency) ).

You can find the details of the proof in most classic statistics textbook, (like [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1573441205800054)), as well as many [lecture](http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/%7Eroger/courses/574/lectures/L9.pdf)
[notes](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.187.7448&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
(search "maximum likelihood asymptotic efficiency")  .